# Issues importing packages

Tags: java

This may be a duplicate, but I can't find any solutions that are similar to mine. (I probably just suck at searching)

I'm currently new and this is the first time actually stepping up to ask a dumb question, but I'm currently trying to important packages but it doesn't recognize my packages. I've created a **com** folder in my C: drive and created two folders named school and home. In the school folder, I have two folders named student and teacher and in the home folder, with multiple classes in each folder. In the home folder, I have a main class that imports the packages from the student and teacher folder, but it won't recognize my packages.

home folder -

hi.java (**import com.school.student.*;*** and **import com.school.teacher.;** )

student folder - 
multiple class files with (package com.school.student;) at the top

teacher folder - 
one class file with (package com.school.teacher;) and (import com.school.students.*;)

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong as it's not recognizing **com.school.student.*;*** and **com.school.teacher.;** in the **hi.java** method.

Comment: which IDE you use? eclipse or netbeans or else ?
do the hi.java in  project separated from your packages ?

Comment: you have to add them into your class path if you are using command prompt to run your java class

Comment: I'm being taught to use only text files at school currently.

Comment: @YohannesGebremariam how might i achieve this?                                            javac -classpath C:\com\java\student hi.java?

Comment: @Anas Basically I have a main folder called com with two folders inside (school and home) and school has two more folders (student and teacher) and I have my main class in the home folder that wants to use the classes in the student and teacher folder.

Comment: To compile(assuming from your root path)  : javac -classpath \com\school\student  ; \com\school\teacher   hi.java

Comment: @YohannesGebremariam am i to run these two statements seperately? because it gives me an error saying invalid flag: ;

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove period(.) from the end of import statements.

Instead of

```
 com.school.student.; 
 com.school.teacher.;
```

use

```
 com.school.student.*; 
 com.school.teacher.*;
```

This will import all the classes from `com.school.student` and `com.school.teacher` packages. It is better to import only those classes which will be used by your class.

You can use any IDE like [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) to code. Both of them are free.

Comment: I forgot to add the asterisk in my post. They were already included in my statement.